# Using Telegram Bot with Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to use my telegram bot with Django. I want the code to keep running in the background. I am Using the apps.py to do this but there's one problem when the bot starts as it's an infinite loop, the Django server is never started.

Apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
import os

class BotConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'bot'
    
    def ready(self):
        from . import jobs

        if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
            jobs.StartBot()
```

Jobs.py:

```
def StartBot():
    
    updater = Updater("API KEY")
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(ChatMemberHandler(GetStatus, ChatMemberHandler.CHAT_MEMBER))
    updater.start_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
    updater.idle()
```

What's the best way to run my bot in the background? while making sure that the Django server runs normally. I tried Django background tasks but it's not compatible with Django 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of [`Updater.idle`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater.idle) is to keep the main thread alive because `start_polling` only starts some background threads that don't block the main thread. If you want to run other stuff in the main thread, skip `updater.idle()` and instead call [`Updater.stop`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater.stop) manually when the program should shut down.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`